# How to create a location picker in angular using google map js api to let user select location

Tags: angular, typescript

How to create a location picker in angular using google map js api to let user select location and save the lang and lat of user

Comment: Here is a guide: https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/. I would recommend rewriting your question since it's not really about Angular and certainly not about TypeScript.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.